# PECL Imagick adaptiveSharpenImage not working?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, pecl

I'm trying to sharpen my images using this function, but it's not working.  Whatever values I pass in for radius and sigma I get an identical image (same file size even) out.

It returns a 1 suggesting no error.  What might be going wrong here?

```
$photo = new Imagick(PHOTOS_DIR.$sFilename);
$photo->adaptiveSharpenImage(2,1);  //4,2 ... 0,10, 0.5,0.5 - all give identical results
$guid = md5(uniqid(rand(),true));
$photo->writeImage(PHOTOS_DIR.'/temp/'.$guid.'.jpg');
```

I tried passing in `imagick::CHANNEL_BLUE` for the optional third parameter, it made no difference.

- CentOS 6.5
- PHP 5.5.12
- pecl-imagick 3.1.2
- imagemagick 6.5.4

Comment: FWIW sharpenImage works, but gives unsatisfactory results.

Comment: I tried `yum remove ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel php55u-pecl-imagick` and `yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel php55u-pecl-imagick` - made no difference

Answer (score 0):

The adaptiveImageSharpen function is ***really*** subtle in some circumstances. The images below are the source and then the sharpened one produced by:

```
$radius = 10;
$sigma = 2;
$imagick->adaptiveSharpenImage($radius, $sigma);
```

### Source image

[image: Source image]

### Sharpened image

[image: Sharpened]

Even at those relatively large values, the image is definitely sharpened but the effect is only noticeable when compared to the source image. The radius you choose will depend on the size of your source image, but ought to be at least a couple of pixels across. Alternatively you can set a radius of zero, and ImageMagick should choose an appropriate value for the image.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve with the sharpening you may be better off with and old fashioned `unsharpMaskImage` if `adaptiveSharpenImage` is always too subtle an effect for you.

Or it could just be broken on the very old version of ImageMagick you're using - can you try with the sample image and settings above.

Comment: Can confirm that it is broken, even on much newer versions:

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23211&hilit=sharpen

Also found reports of it not working back in 2007 - clearly a troublesome bit of code for the IM guys!

Comment: And it insults me that you think I wouldn't have noticed a subtle effect :P  I tried it with countless different parameters and the file size was unchanged to the byte in every case.